# How to redirect URL when select and click button

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to redirect URL when selectbox selected and click Go button?
This is what I just tried.

```
 <script>
        function goCenter(){
            var addrCenter = $("#selCenter").val();
            location.href = addrCenter;

        }
        </script>
        <select id="selCenter"> 
                    <option value='http://ebay.com' selected="selected">ebay</option>
                    <option value='http://google.com'>google</option> 
                </select>

        <button onchange="goCenter();">go</button>
```

This is not working to me. Please help

Comment: why not `onclick` event instead of `onchange`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try with `onclick` instead of `onchange`. Let's try

```js
        function goCenter(){
            var addrCenter = $("#selCenter").val();
            console.log(addrCenter);
            location.href = addrCenter;
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="selCenter"> 
                    <option value='http://ebay.com' selected="selected">ebay</option>
                    <option value='http://google.com'>google</option> 
                </select>

        <button onclick="goCenter();">go</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this.

```
$('button').on('click', goCenter);

function goCenter(){
        var addrCenter = $("#selCenter option:selected").val();
        location.href = addrCenter;
    }
```

You would not need the “onchange="goCenter();" in the button element.